# Runtime for Assignment Part of Radix Sort

Tags: radix-sort, array-algorithms

How would you describe the runtime analysis of the following bit of code? It is the second step in radix sort (first step is creating the counter).

```
   const reAssignArraySlots = (arr, counter) => {
      let i = 0;
      let j = 0;
      while(i<arr.length) {
        let k = 0;
        let num = counter[i] || 0;
        while(k<num) {
          arr[j] = i;
          k+=1;
          j+=1;
        }
        i+=1;
        j+=1;
      }
      return arr;
    };
```

I believe it would be O(n) no matter what, but wanted to check that intuition. Examples:

A) All the elements are the same. The counter would be { '2': 3 }. The while loop with i would process 1x, the while loop with k would process 3x, and each insertion would be O(1). I add up the 3 insertions to make O(3) which is O(n)

B) All the elements are unique. The counter would be { '2': 1, '1': 1, '3': 1 }. The while loop would process i 3x. Each insertion would be O(1) which would add up to O(3) which is O(n).

C) Non-unique, non-sequential elements. { '4': 1, '1': 1, '3': 2 }. Here I am unsure. We'd have O(1) for each insertion, but we'd have an additional check for i = 2, which isn't in here. Not sure if that bumps us up to O(4). Eventually if we had something sparse enough, this could get O(n^2).

Rest of the Code:

```
    const getCounter = (arr) => {
  const counter = {};
  let min, max;
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if(counter[item] !== undefined) {
      counter[item] += 1;
    } else {
      counter[item] = 1;
    }
  });
  return counter;
};

export const countSort = (arr) => {
  const counter = getCounter(arr);
  return reAssignArraySlots(arr, counter);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 nested loops, so I would be inclined to say it's no slower than O(n^2).

1. `i` is incremented in the outer loop
2. `k` is incremented in the inner loop (and set to zero before the loop)
3. `j` is incremented in both loops

`k` could be different for each loop, but lets say there's an average to it `ave_k`
At the end of the loop, it seems to me that `j` would always be equal to `i * ave_k`.

The big question is what is the magnitude of `k` (or `ave_k`)?

- is it proportional to `i`? Then you've got O(n^2).
- is it proportional to `ln(i)`? Then you've got O(n ln(n) ).
- is it constant, independant from `i`?  Then you've got O(n).
- is it typically the square of `i`? Then you've got O(n^2)
- is it typically the square root of `i`? Then you've got O(n sqrt(n) )